# How to set the PropType of a mobx store?

Tags: javascript, eslint, mobx, react-proptypes

I’m using here: ***React***, ***ESLint***, ***Mobx***.

I'm not sure **how to set correctly the PropType of a mobx store I pass with the Provider**.

**ESLint** gives me this **error**:

> [eslint] store is missing in props validation (react/prop-types)

Im passing a store through a `Provider` like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    appLocation
);
```

in `App` component I use one of the store values, 
this is my my ***mobx store***:

```
import { observable } from 'mobx';

class Store{
    @observable x = 'Hello World!';
}

export const store= new Store();
```

and this is my ***App Component***:

```
// Dependencies
import React from 'react';
import { inject, observer } from 'mobx-react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

// Components
import TestComponent from './TestComponent';

// App Component
@inject('store')
@observer
export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <TestComponent store={this.props.store} />     // the Error above
            </div>
        );
    }
}

App.propType = {
    store: PropTypes.any    // What is the correct way to set this prop?
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a small typo. It is `propTypes`, not `propType`:

```
@inject('store')
@observer
export default class App extends React.Component {
    static propTypes = {
        store: PropTypes.any
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <TestComponent store={this.props.store} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: It realy was a typo, thanks,
but I get this error: `Warning: Failed prop type: The prop 'store' is marked as required in inject-App-with-store, but its value is undefined.
    in inject-App-with-store`

Comment: The second error I had was caused because @inject decorates the component and also wraps the component with a component named *wrappedComponent*, so when addressing inside **propTypes**, it needs to be like this: `App.wrappedComponent.propTypes = {...}`.

Answer (score 1):

`store: PropTypes.object.isRequired` or `store: PropTypes.object` should do the thing.

In case you have the rule *Prop type `any` is forbidden: eslint(react/forbid-prop-types)* `store: PropTypes.any` (required or not) will just work.